# Calculating overall and relative efficiency

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, average, percentages

Firstly, I'm not a mathematics major and this is my first question here so please be gentle.

### My attempt at a simple calculation of efficiency . . .

$\mathtt n$ = (# of cases of ingredients)

$\mathtt b$ = (target yield per case) = 17

$\mathtt x$ = (total actual yield)

$\mathtt f(x,n)$ = $\frac{x}{bn}$ = (overall efficiency)

---

### The problematic scenario . . .

Normally, the above is true. However, consider the following:

$\mathtt n_1$ = 30

$\mathtt n_2$ = 100

$\mathtt x$ = 0

$\mathtt f(x,n_1)$ $\neq$ $\mathtt f(x,n_2)$

*NOTE: The last statement above is not true. The results of those two functions are both zero. Keep reading.*

---

### Question

What I am trying to describe here is this: yielding no product from 100 cases is clearly worse than yielding no product from 30 cases, but my efficiency formula will show both as 0%.

It seems there is a fundamental flaw in my approach, but I'm not familiar with mathematics enough to know what it is. Any suggestions about how else I could go about this?